# Javascript in Visual studio Web Api

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript function embeded in my html code but when i'm running the page i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined.

I'm also using angularjs, so i have my index page and, as they explain, my partial page, and that functioon is in my partial page.

When i double click the web page from the folder i can run the script, but when i run the web api it present that error.

My javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          var x;
          var r = confirm("Press a button!");
          if (r == true) {
              x = "You pressed OK!";
          }
          else {
              x = "You pressed Cancel!";
          }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
```

and how i call it:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

can anyone help me?
thk

Comment: What is actually *"Visual studio Web Api"*? Also have a look [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is trying to use the function even before it is loaded. Can you try below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function myLoad() {
          var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

          myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
             var x;
             var r = confirm("Press a button!");
             if (r == true) {
                x = "You pressed OK!";
             }
             else {
                x = "You pressed Cancel!";
             }

             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
          }, false);
       }

       window.load = myLoad;
</script>
```

Finally add an Id to the button.

```
<button id="myButton">Try it</button>
```